# SharePoint 2016 - JSLink - save not working with IE but working with Chrome

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I've got a strange behaviour with a JSLINK I'm using on my SP. The save button of the form is not working with IE if I change the value of the field that the JSLINK is transforming but it's ok with Chrome.

The field is type of Multiline plain text. I'm using using to save some JSON.

Here is the code:

```js
(function() {
    var loaded = false;

    var repeaterFormArr = [
        "<input type='text' id='nameInput' placeholder='Nom complet' class='ms-long ms-spellcheck-true intervenantsBox' required>",
        "<input type='text' id='addressInput' placeholder='Adresse' class='ms-long ms-spellcheck-true intervenantsBox'>",
        "<input type='text' id='phoneInput' placeholder='Telephone' class='ms-long ms-spellcheck-true intervenantsBox'>",
        "<input type='text' id='emailInput' placeholder='Email' pattern=\"[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$\" title='xxx@yyy.zzz' class='ms-long ms-spellcheck-true intervenantsBox'>",
        "<select name='typeActor' id='typeActor' class='ms-long intervenantsBox'><option value='plaignant'>Plaignant</option><option value='avocat'>Avocat</option><option value='DPO'>DPO</option><option value='demandeur'>Demandeur</option></select>",
    ];

    var ControlRenderModeIntervenant;
    var repeaterFormValues = [];

    function includeCss() {
        if (loaded) return;
        loaded = true;
        var link = document.createElement('link');
        link.href = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + '/Style%20Library/CSS/intervenantsEditCustom.css';
        link.rel = 'stylesheet';
        document.head.appendChild(link);
    }

    // This function provides the rendering logic
    function IntervenantsRepeaterFiledViewTemplate(ctx) {
        ControlRenderModeIntervenant = ctx.ControlMode;

        if (ctx.CurrentItem[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name] && ctx.CurrentItem[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name] != '[]') {
            var fieldValue = ctx.CurrentItem[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name].replace(/&quot;/g, "\"").replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/g, "");
            repeaterFormValues = JSON.parse(fieldValue);
        }

        return GetRenderHtmlRepeaterValuesIntervenants();
    }

    // This function provides the rendering logic
    function IntervenantsRepeaterFiledEditFTemplate(ctx) {
        var field = ctx.CurrentFieldSchema,
            encodedName = field.Name + '_' + field.Id + '_$NumberField';

        ControlRenderModeIntervenant = ctx.ControlMode;

        var formCtx = SPClientTemplates.Utility.GetFormContextForCurrentField(ctx);

        if (formCtx.fieldValue) {
            repeaterFormValues = JSON.parse(formCtx.fieldValue);
        }

        // Register a callback just before submit.
        ctx.FormContext.registerGetValueCallback(field.Name, function() {
            return JSON.stringify(repeaterFormValues);
        });
        ctx.FormContext.registerInitCallback(field.Name, function() {
            document.getElementById('innerFormIntervenants').addEventListener('submit', function(evt) {
                evt.preventDefault();
                AddIntervenant();
                return false;
            });
            var deleteLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('delete-link');
            if (deleteLinks.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < deleteLinks.length; i++) {
                    deleteLinks[i].addEventListener("onclick", function(evt) {
                        evt.preventDefault();
                        DeleteItem(deleteLinks[i].getAttribute('data-myAttri'));
                        return false;
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        // formCtx.registerGetValueCallback(formCtx.fieldName, function() {
        //     return JSON.stringify(repeaterFormValues);
        // });


        var HTMLViewTemplate = "<form id='innerFormIntervenants'>{Controls}<div><input type='submit' value='Add' style='margin-left:0'></div><br/><div id='divRepeaterValues'>{RepeaterValues}</div><br/></form>";
        var returnHTML = "";

        for (index = 0; index < repeaterFormArr.length; ++index) {
            returnHTML += repeaterFormArr[index];
        }

        returnHTML = HTMLViewTemplate.replace(/{Controls}/g, returnHTML);
        returnHTML = returnHTML.replace(/{RepeaterValues}/g, GetRenderHtmlRepeaterValuesIntervenants());

        return returnHTML;
    }

    function GetRenderHtmlRepeaterValuesIntervenants() {

        var index;
        var innerindex;
        var HTMLItemsTemplate = "<table width='600px' style='border:1px solid #ababab;'>{Items}</table>";
        var HTMLItemTemplate = "<tr>{Item}</tr>";
        var HTMLValueTemplate = "<td>{Value}</td>";

        if (ControlRenderModeIntervenant == SPClientTemplates.ClientControlMode.EditForm || ControlRenderModeIntervenant == SPClientTemplates.ClientControlMode.NewForm) {
            HTMLItemTemplate = "<tr>{Item}<td><a class='delete-link' data-myAttri='{Index}' href='#'><img src='/SiteAssets/IMG/user-delete.png' class='deleteUserButton'/></a></td></tr>";
        }

        var returnHTML = "";
        var tempValueHtml;


        for (index = 0; index < repeaterFormValues.length; ++index) {
            tempValueHtml = "";

            for (innerindex = 0; innerindex < repeaterFormValues[index]["Intervenant"].length; ++innerindex) {
                tempValueHtml += HTMLValueTemplate.replace(/{Value}/g, repeaterFormValues[index]["Intervenant"][innerindex]["Value"]);
            }

            returnHTML += HTMLItemTemplate.replace(/{Item}/g, tempValueHtml);
            returnHTML = returnHTML.replace(/{Index}/g, index);
        }

        if (repeaterFormValues.length) {
            returnHTML = HTMLItemsTemplate.replace(/{Items}/g, returnHTML);
        }

        return returnHTML;
    }

    function AddIntervenant() {

        var innerFormIntervenants = document.getElementById('innerFormIntervenants');

        if (innerFormIntervenants.checkValidity()) {

            var index;
            var tempRepeaterValue = [];

            for (index = 0; index < innerFormIntervenants.length; index++) {

                if (innerFormIntervenants[index].type != "submit" && innerFormIntervenants[index].type != "button" && innerFormIntervenants[index].type != "reset") {
                    tempRepeaterValue.push({
                        "ID": innerFormIntervenants[index].id,
                        "Value": innerFormIntervenants[index].value
                    });

                    innerFormIntervenants[index].value = "";
                }
            }

            repeaterFormValues.push({ "Intervenant": tempRepeaterValue });

            document.getElementById("divRepeaterValues").innerHTML = GetRenderHtmlRepeaterValuesIntervenants();
        }
    }

    function DeleteItem(index) {
        repeaterFormValues.splice(index, 1);
        document.getElementById("divRepeaterValues").innerHTML = GetRenderHtmlRepeaterValuesIntervenants();
    }

    var overrideCtx = {};
    overrideCtx.Templates = {};
    overrideCtx.Templates.OnPreRender = includeCss;
    overrideCtx.Templates.Fields = {
        myCustomField: {
            View: IntervenantsRepeaterFiledViewTemplate,
            DisplayForm: IntervenantsRepeaterFiledViewTemplate,
            NewForm: IntervenantsRepeaterFiledEditFTemplate,
            EditForm: IntervenantsRepeaterFiledEditFTemplate
        }
    };

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);
})();
```

In Debug, I can see that the callback function is called. Then it goes inside the JS of SharePoint for saving the item. But the save button is just going to grey and then nothing append.

Comment: Well, after investigation, it seems that IE refuse to save only when the returned value of the JSON increase. I can delete object from inside the JSON and the save happen correctly. But I can't add items.

Comment: So, continuing to investigate. Only Edge and Internet Explorer are concerned. This is something that happen in the js of SharePoint not mine, when it "validate" field. I don't know exactly what. There is no error of any kind or warning returned during the debug process.